# Call function onPress React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just want to know how to call a function `onPress`. I've setup my code like this:

```
export default class Tab3 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {myColor: "green"};
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        if (this.state.color === 'green'){
           this.setState({myColor: 'blue'});
        } else {
           this.setState({myColor: 'green'});
        }
    }

    render() {
     return(
      <View>
           <Icon
            name='heart'
            color={this.state.myColor}
            size= {45}
            style={{marginLeft:40}}
            onPress={() => handleClick(this)}                                 
            />
      </View>
      )};
```

But when I try this, I'm getting error that `can't find variable handleClick`

Please help. I just want to know how to bind a function to a click event.

Comment: You declared `handleClick` as a property of the class; an instance method. Thus you have to use `this` to signify the current instance, and access it from there: `this.handleClick`.

Comment: Also, the inline arrow function in `onPress` is completely unnecessary because `handleClick` is already an arrow function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In you're render you're setting up the handler incorrectly, give this a try;

```
 <View>
       <Icon
        name='heart'
        color={this.state.myColor}
        size= {45}
        style={{marginLeft:40}}
        onPress={this.handleClick}                                 
        />
  </View>
```

The syntax you're using would make sense for declaring an anonymous function inline or something but since your handler is defined on the class, you just reference it (not call it) using `this.functionName` in the props.

Comment: I tried by creating an `Alert` for the handleClick whenever its called. So I get the alert the first time but not the second time.

Comment: Sorry, I get the alert each time, but the color doesn't change.

Comment: @Somename one thing that might be causing it; `if (this.state.color === 'green')` that should be `this.state.myColor`

Comment: I'm an ignorant pos .. `if (this.state.color` is wrong .. i changed that to `if (this.state.myColor` and everything is tip top now .. working absolutely flawless. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Somename np, happy to help.

Answer (score 12):

A little late to the party, but just wanted to leave this here if someone needs it

```
export default class mainScreen extends Component {

handleClick = () => {
 //some code
}

render() {
 return(
  <View>
       <Button
        name='someButton'
        onPress={() => {
            this.handleClick(); //usual call like vanilla javascript, but uses this operator
         }}                                 
        />
  </View>
  )};
```

Comment: This works, but refer to the React docs for optimal performance: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

"Using Function.prototype.bind in render creates a new function each time the component renders, which may have performance implications (see below)."

The correct way would be `onPress={this.handleClick}`

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the method with the `this` keyword.

```
 <Icon
    onPress={this.handleClick}                                 
  />
```

Comment: Fairly certain `onPress` is a prop for the react component (it's not a native html element) so no binding is necessary.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal ooh gotcha

Comment: @evanmcdonnal It's not that binding isn't necessary because it's React Native, but because it's an arrow function class property. `this` inside the function already refers to the component, not something else.

Comment: It worked with binding and without it. Problem is, it works only once. It changes to color Blue but on click again doesn't change back to green.

Comment: @Somename Did you mean `this.state.myDynamicColor`, not `this.state.color`?

Comment: @AndrewLi .. Sorry, edited the question. Its `myColor`

Comment: @Somename put a breakpoint in your handler and verify it's being called the second time around when you're expecting it to switch back to green. Chances are it's not, the code is very simple and the updating of `this.state.myColor` will force a re-render. The logic in the handler is correct. Also, should `onPress` be `onClick`? you just described the second action as a click which makes me think maybe it should be.

Comment: Oh, im testing on Android simulator, it should be `onPress` cause its an app, if thats what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this way of binding

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
```

and put this inside constructor. And while calling use this syntax

```
onPress = {this.handleClick}
```

This will surely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using class components, you can just drop the ***this***

This function can handle the navigation for any route (as long as there is one screen with the name passed as the argument) removing the need for multiple handlers.

```
const navigation = useNavigation(); 

function handleNavigation(route) {
    navigation.navigate(route);
}
```

and the button will look like this:

```
<Button onPress={() => handleNavigation("Menu")} ></Button>
```